# How to efficiently compute a representation of a complex number by basis in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Given a complex number $c =a+bi \in \mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$, where $\zeta$ is the $2^n$-th root of unity, i.e., $\zeta^{2^n}=1$.
Since $\phi(2^n)=2^{n-1}$, how to efficiently compute a representation of $c$:
$$\displaystyle c=\sum_{i=0}^{2^{n-1}-1} d_i \zeta^i,d_i\in \mathbb{Z}?$$

$a$ and $b$ are not necessary integers, for example, assume $\zeta^8=1$, we have
$c=a+bi=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i=0+\zeta+0\zeta^2+\cdots+0\zeta^3.$

In other words, I know that  $c \in \mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$ is a cyclotomic integer, but I don't know its coefficients $d_i$.
Thereby, I hope there is efficient algorithm which could output those $d_i$ with small running time complexity, for example, $O(n2^n)$ or less.

Comment: We have $i=\zeta^{2^{n-2}}$ or its negative, depending on the choice of $\zeta$. Does that not solve it immediately? Or, did you mean that $a,b$ are not necessarily integers?

Comment: If you did not mean $a$ and $b$ to be integers, then how are they given/described? The answer surely depends on that.

Comment: For example, when $n\ge3$ the cyclotomic integers form a dense subset of the complex plane. This means that it is very difficult (if not impossible) to use decimal expansions of $a$ and $b$. Those necessarily have a limited accuracy. But density means that to each $\varepsilon>0$ and each $c\in\Bbb{C}$ there are infinitely many cyclotomic integers $\tilde{c}$ such that $|c-\tilde{c}|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: An algebraic integer is usually defined by a monic integer polynomial it is a root of. Do you have such a polynomial?

Comment: @reuns I have no such polynomials. Suppose that someone compute a complex number $c=\sum_{i=0}^{2^{n-1}-1} d_i \zeta^i,d_i\in \mathbb{Z}$, and only give me $c=a+bi$, can I recover those information of $d_i$?

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen $a$  and $b$ are not necessary integers. I put a simple example in the question. Suppose someone only give me a $c=a+bi$, Can I efficiently recover those $d_i$ when I know that $c$ is generated by $\sum_i d_i \zeta^i$?

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen If it is impossible to recover those $d_i$ precisely, is it possible to efficiently approximate $c$ with very small $\varepsilon$?

Comment: How are $a$ and $b$ given when that someone writes down $a+bi$? You didn't answer that.

Comment: For example, when $n=3$, $\sqrt2=\zeta+\zeta^7=\zeta-\zeta^3$ is a cyclotomic integer. Hence so is
$$(\sqrt2-1)^{100}=94741125149636933417873079920900017937-66992092050551637663438906713182313772 \sqrt{2}\approx5.2775\cdot 10^{-39}.$$ Whoever gives you $c=a+bi$ must be precise enough to distinguish that from zero. As you see, it makes a huge difference in the coefficients $d_i$.

Comment: Mind you, there may be algorithms for finding the closest match, if you place a constraint like $|d_i|<10$ for all $i$, but I don't know any. May be someone well versed in [tag:diophantine-approximation] can say more?.

Comment: The exact formula for $d_i$ in terms of $c$ involve, in addition to $c$ itself, its images under the automorphisms of the cyclotomic field. Actually it suffices to give one of a pair of complex conjugates. In the case $n=3$ we need, in addition of $c$, also $\sigma(c)$, where $\sigma$ is the automorphism determined by $\sigma(\zeta)=\zeta^3$. It follows that $\sigma(\sqrt2)=-\sqrt2$. So in the above example you would also be given
$$(-\sqrt2-1)^{100}=94741125149636933417873079920900017937+66992092050551637663438906713182313772 \sqrt{2}\approx1.8948\cdot10^{38}.$$

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen Thank you very much. I think I understand more about cyclotomic integers from your example. An upper bound for $|d_i|$ seems very important, or a tinny difference of $c$ will deduce a huge difference in the coefficients $d_i$.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen I find a paper: [Approximation of Complex Numbers by Cyclotomic Integers](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.54.5539&rep=rep1&type=pdf). It seems the authors provide an algorithm to find close match. It also requires $|d_i|<M$. If we restrict $|d_i|<M$, will that tiny difference of $c$ still deduce huge difference of $d_i$? i.e., most of $|d_i-d_{i'}|$ have relative large value.

Comment: The authors of that paper surely can say more about it than I can do. But I can say the following. Bounding the coefficients $d_i$ also gives a roughly same size bound on the coefficients of the Galois conjugates. In my numerical example you saw that the coefficients of the conjugates had the same size. This implies that there is a bound on the complex absolute value of all the conjugates. And for a cyclotomic integer the product of all the conjugates is an integer (or a Gaussian integer if you only include one each complex conjugate pairs).

Comment: (cont'd) This means roughly something like follows. With $|d_i|<M$ for all $i$, all the conjugates satisfy $|\sigma(c)|< K\cdot M$ for some constant $K$. As there are $2^{n-2}$ of them (include only one of complex conjugate pairs), it follows that any non-zero cyclotomic integer also satisfies the lower bound $|c|>1/(KM)^{2^{n-2}}$. This isn't much, but it does show that for small $M$, the numbers cannot be arbitrarily close to each other. IIRC this is in some sense the best possible lower bound.

Comment: (cont'd)  As you see, this is very sensitive to $M$. Meaning that relatively small errors may significantly affect the coefficients $d_i$. In the powers $(\sqrt2\pm1)$ above you see that the product of those two complicated numbers is exactly $1$. That's because $\sqrt2-1$ is a unit of the ring of cyclotomic integers.